# H heading + some other text on the same line

Tags: html, css, html-heading

I am trying to have a heading  and then some less important text on the same line:

### Skill Ratings

(scale of 5)

but I really want `(scale of 5)` to be in the same line as well as that `Skill Ratings` be wrapped in the `<h>` tags for document structure semantics.

I am tight on real estate so I don't want another line, `(scale of 5)` will be linked to a CSS style.

Is this possible? If not, I will chose to not have `Skill Ratings` as a heading but would prefer that it be.

Comment: And your actual HTML would be..?

Comment: something like `<span class="extHeading"><h3>Skill Ratings</h3>(scale of 5)</span>`

Comment: Wrap everything in a `div` and float the elements so they line up or use `absolute` and `relative` positioning.

Comment: but then again, i don't know -- that is why i am asking this question to find out.  I want to have **Skill Ratings** `(scale of 5)` all in one line where "Skill Ratings" is recognized as a heading and "(scale of 5)" is not, yet is on the same line

Answer (score 27, accepted):

HTML

```
<h1>Skill Ratings <span>(scale of 5)</span></h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 span { font-size:16px; }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use Lowkase's answer, or if for some reason you needed to separate the elements into Headings and Paragraph tags, you could do this:

```
<h1>Skill Ratings </h1>

<p>(scale of 5)</p>
```

Then here is the css:

```
.h1 { display: inline; }
.p { display: inline; }
```

Lowkase's solution is more semantic, so it's probably a better solution, but this is another way to do it.

## EDIT

Sorry, I just noticed you wanted it in the header tag, which means use Lowkase's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just make your `<h1>` display:inline. This way, it will render in the normal text flow.

[Fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFZ2S/)

```
<h1>Skill Ratings </h1>(scale of 5)

h1 {
    display:inline
}
```

Comment: Can anyone explain why is this not recommended (judging from the -1 on the answer)?

Comment: i can't, sorry. I thought i misunderstood the question "have a heading and then some less important text on the same line"  meaning for me H1 /H1  + some text .. Maybe op was changed and the answer is no longer relevant .. I don't know.  The 'scale of 5' is in outter parent element, less semantic form. ??

Comment: This worked fine for me so +1. The OP wasn't very clear about wanting the `(scale of 5)` within the `h1` tag.

Comment: Link is broken at the moment. Does that solution work with `style="display:inline"` also?